# When using javascript in vscode, copying and pasting to function causes column disruption

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image]

This format is fixed.

Regardless how many space there are, first row have two space, and following lines have no space.

I think it is related to option, but i don't know what it is.

I execute "reindent line" to solve this problem, but I can only solve this problem temporarily.

I want to solve this problem permanently.

Comment: What's the value of your `editor.autoIndent` setting? The default value is `"full"`. Did you change it to something else like `"none"`?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask